# Analytic structures on the source of a surjection of condensed rings

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rigid-analytic-geometry, condensed-mathematics

**Question.** Let $(\mathcal B,\mathcal N)$ be an analytic (animated associative) ring, $\mathcal A$ be a condensed (animated associative) ring and $f\colon\mathcal A\to\mathcal B$ a surjective map of condensed rings, i.e., it induces a surjection on $\pi_0$.

1. Do we always have an analytic structure $\mathcal M$ on $\mathcal A$ such that $\mathcal N$ coincides with the induced analytic structure given by $\mathcal M_B[S]:=\mathcal B[S]\otimes_{\mathcal A}^L(\mathcal A,\mathcal M)$ for all extremally disconnected sets $S$?
2. Is there always a final analytic structure $\mathcal M$ on $\mathcal A$ satisfying the condition above?

---

First, by the "topological invariance of analytic structure" in [Lectures on Analytic Geometry](https://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/scholze/Analytic.pdf) (by the way, this does not seem to be a good terminology because "topological" is more referring to topological spaces than homotopy types), if I am not mistaken, we could assume that both $\mathcal A$ and $\mathcal B$ are static, and thus $\mathcal A\to\mathcal B$ is simply a surjective map of static condensed rings. However, this does **not** imply that $\mathcal M[S]$ is static for all extremally disconnected sets $S$.

---

I checked this for the simplest case that $\mathcal A=A$ is a discrete (commutative) ring, $(\mathcal B,\mathcal N)$ is given by a discrete Huber pair $(B,B^+)$ and $f\colon A\to B$ is a surjective map of discrete rings.

In this case, seemingly we could take $A^+:=f^{-1}(B^+)\subseteq A$. Given any monic polynomial $P(T)\in A^+[T]$ and any $x\in A$ such that $P(x)=0$, we have $(f^*P)(f(x))=0$ where $f^*\colon A^+[T]\to B^+[T]$ is the induced map. Since $B^+\subseteq B$ is integrally closed, $f(x)\in B^+$, which implies that $x\in A^+$. In this case, the map $f\colon(A,A^+)\to(B,B^+)$ is a map of discrete Huber rings therefore also of analytic rings. It then follows from the surjectivity that the solidification $(B,B^+)_\blacksquare$ coincides with the induced analytic structure.

**Example.** When $A\to B$ is given by $\mathbb Q[T]\to\mathbb Q,T\mapsto0$ and $B^+=\mathbb Z$, we have $A^+=\mathbb Z+T\cdot\mathbb Q[T]$.

Moreover, $(A,A^+)$ is obviously the final discrete Huber pair satisfying the condition. It seems reasonable to guess that this is also final as an analytic ring.

---

**Update.** The guess about the finality seems to be incorrect: consider the trivial case that $B$ is the zero ring, then $A^+=A$ but the final analytic structure on $A$ seems to be zero.

**Update for motivation:** $\DeclareMathOperator\AnSpec{AnSpec}$This is part of effort to understand what is the correct "closed embedding" of analytic rings / analytic spectra. It seems reasonable to assume that "closed subset" should have the induced analytic structure (it should be "partially proper"). When $\mathcal A\to\mathcal B$ is surjective, $\AnSpec(\mathcal B,\mathcal N)\to\AnSpec(\mathcal B)\to\AnSpec(\mathcal A)$ could be understood as a composition of embeddings of which the second is closed, then the analytic ring $(\mathcal A,\mathcal M)$ that I seek looks like another factorization $\AnSpec(\mathcal B,\mathcal N)\to\AnSpec(\mathcal A,\mathcal M)\to\AnSpec(\mathcal A)$ of this embedding of which the first embedding is "closed", i.e., "switching" the closedness to the first. Compare with the "immersions" (or locally closed embeddings) in algebraic geometry.

Comment: This question seems a bit weird to me, to be honest. Is there any reason to believe such a thing ought to exist?

Comment: @PeterScholze I have included a motivation (which is slightly different from how I got it). In particular, one usually embeds a scheme as a closed subscheme of a "good" scheme (such as affine space and projective space) then one could perform several operations to this closed subscheme. I was trying to understand an analytic analogue.

Comment: I see, that's helpful! You are right that closed immersion should include "partially proper"=induced analytic ring structure. But I'm not sure about the precise motivation: It ought to be true that anything that's sufficiently "finitely presented" should have such closed immersions into affine space (locally), for some suitable definitions; but I think you want to specify the ambient analytic ring structure on affine space a priori, it shouldn't be imposed a posteriori by the closed subscheme.

Comment: @PeterScholze I don't plan to impose any kind of finiteness. My algebraic model is $R$ being a quasisyntomic $A$-algebra and one factors $A\to R$ as $A\to P\to R$ where $P$ is ind-polynomial (this might be weakened to quasismooth + Frobenius being flat for all primes). For sake of simplicity, take the base to be $\mathbb Z$ and consider an analytic ring $(\mathcal A,\mathcal M)$. By "analytic structure a priori", do you mean that it is possible to take a "free analytic ring" of which the generators could "manage" not only the structure of $\mathcal A$ but also that of $\mathcal M$? ...

Comment: [cont'd] I did not believe the possibility of this. I don't believe that the category of analytic rings has projective generators. I suppose that in the formal definition of analytic rings, one should impose that $\mathcal M$ is left Kan extended from $\kappa$-small extremally disconnected sets, I can conceive that the datum involved is essentially small.